# Future of civilization in our solar system - AI or Human?

Tags: life

Which civilization type from Earth is most likely to exist one million years from now?

1) Human/Biological
2) Artificial Intelligence
3) Both
4) Neither

Interested in any enlightening comments. Personally, I don't see human civilization standing much of a chance on this time scale but always open to interesting thoughts. How long do you think humans/human civilization can survive?

Comment: Welcome to *Space!* This question is more fiction (or speculation) than science, and is therefore *off-topic* for this site. However, you may want to check the *WorldBuilding* StackExchange site. If the question has not already been answered there, you may want to ask there.